# javascript framework for ipad safari browser and desktop web browser

Tags: ipad, browser, safari, javascript-framework

i am in the process of selecting a technology for building an application which would be targeted on the ipad safari browser or the normal desktop web browser. I am leaned towards YUI since it has mobile support and custom libraries. i am not going for DOJO since it doesnt support addition of custom features on their libraries and not GWT because it is a single page application which causes the flow between pages very slow. any ideas are welcome

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/).

Comment: any good books for jquey mobile involving spring mvc, hibernate for mysql db

Answer (score 0):

[Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) uses all the latest doodads in webkit, and if you're only looking at Apple OS's you would be insane not to look at it as a framework - but then again, I do work for Sencha. In addition to the aforementioned JQuery Mobile, you should also take a look at [jqTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com) if you want to stick with a markup based approach. (BTW, there's nothing inherently slow about an SPA. A well programmed SPA should be lower latency than a page-driven one.)

Comment: any problem with YUI since the application is not heavy on UI but some AJAX components